# Raise text out of the paper plane (with shadows as well)

Tags: raise, shadows

How would one achieve an "raised-text-box-effect (with added shadows)" like in the picture below for *`G(V, E)`* (the `\raisebox` command apparently isn't meant for this task):

[image: raised text-box]

Comment: You can use a simple LaTeX-Command `\shadowbox`. Alternativ you use tikz or pstricks.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel You've meant `\shadowbox` from the [`fancybox`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancybox) package? Because (using `MikTeX 2.7` and `TeXworks`) I **can only use  
[`\shabox`](http://www.langbein.org/publish/latex/latex-2.pdf)** (not `\shadowbox`) from the `\usepackage{shadow}`.  

Also, even with `\shabox` "working", I don't know how to set, say, the box's size.

Comment: The package fanycybox uses only simple rule commands to provide the shadowbox-command. This was the command I meant. Here an example: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}
Text \shadowbox{$G(V,e)$} Text
\end{document}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Yes, that is working. Thank you (and thank god for MikTeX's Package Manager). Would you also know, how to get it subtler (as in above image)?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel OK, I got these [two rules](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancybox/fancybox-doc.pdf) (for box and shadow size):  
`\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}%`  
`\setlength{\shadowsize}{1pt}%`
How would you _soften_ the shadows?

Comment: `fancybox` has no option to "soft" the shadow. You can define your own shadobox with tikz to set such an environment. An example is given on [texample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/system-combination/). In relation to the link (UNTESTED):`\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows}
\tikzstyle{shadownode}{draw,fill=blue!20,dropshadow,anchor=west}
\begin{document}Text\tikz[baseline=current bounding box.west]\node[shadownode]{$G(V,e)$};\end{document}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel _tikz_ it is then, I'll have a look. Thank you Marco for all the help (I'll make a note to upvote as soon as I'm eligible).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcommand{\raisedtext}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [baseline=(X.base)]\node [drop shadow,fill=white,draw,very thin] (X) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
Text \raisedtext{Hello World!} Text
\end{document}
```

[image]